# Syntax error running twython with Qpython on Android device

Tags: android, python, twython, qpython

I am stuck trying to run a script that uses twython, with qpython on an Android device. I have upgraded every module I can see until I eventually narrowed down to this syntax invalid error:

```
/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/motivateMe - Copy.py" && exit
ts3/motivateMe - Copy.py" && exit        <
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/motivateMe - Copy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twython import Twython
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/twython/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .api import Twython
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/twython/api.py", line 15, in <module>
    import requests
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 169
    for prefix in [u'*.', u'.']:
                       ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Python 2 and 3.  In Python2 you can write something like `u'foo'` and it is a `unicode` literal (multibyte per character).  Or `'foo'` and it is a `str` (one byte per character).

In Python3 you can write something like `'foo'` and it is a `str` (which is unicode, i. e. multibyte per character) or `b'foo'` which is `bytes` (one byte per character).

Try to remove the `u` before the `'*.'` etc., that should fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks Alfe. I should have mentioned I am new to Python. I will give that a try.